# Changing TreeNode font's style

Tags: delphi, vcl

I want to display one node's font style, so the first half of the text would be regular, and the second half would be bold.
Here is the following code I tried (simplified code):

```
procedure TMyForm.tvDetailsAdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView; Node: TTreeNode;
  State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var PaintImages, DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  xRect: TRect;
  xLabel, xValue: string;
begin
  if Stage <> cdPostPaint then
    Exit;

  DefaultDraw := False;
  
  if cdsSelected in State then
  begin
    tvDetails.Canvas.Font.Color := ColorToRGB(clHighlightText);
    tvDetails.Canvas.Brush.Color := ColorToRGB(clHighlight);
  end;

  xRect := Node.DisplayRect(False);
  xRect.Left := xRect.Left + ((Node.Level + 1) * tvDetails.Indent);
  tvDetails.Canvas.FillRect(xRect);

  xLabel := 'label';
  xValue := 'value';

  tvDetails.Canvas.TextOut(xRect.Left + 2, xRect.Top + 2, xLabel);
  // the following line has no effect ...
  tvDetails.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  tvDetails.Canvas.TextOut(175, xRect.Top + 2, xValue);
end;
```

Unfortunately the `tvDetails.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];` does nothing, the whole line displayed with regular text. What do I miss here?

Comment: Try doing your drawing in the `cdPrePaint` stage instead of `cdPostPaint`.  Also, consider using `TextRect()` instead of `TextOut()`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, not working, same result. Also changing PostPaint to PrePaint causes that the TreView not painting the node connector lines, +/- signs anymore.